# value for <apex:inputField> is not a dynamic binding!

Tags: apex, visualforce

Why do I get this error: **value for apex:inputField is not a dynamic binding!** ?

My **return page** is supposed to display details from both **Order_Form__c** and **Order__c** objects automatically upon searching a certain order form record from the lookup field on the **Return__c** object. But every time I hit the preview button, there comes the said error.

Here's my controller:

**ReturnManagementCX**

```
public with sharing class ReturnManagementCX {

    private ApexPages.StandardController con;
    public Return__c returnRecord {get;set;}
    public Order_Form__c ordformqry {get;set;}
    public List<resultWrapper> ordwrapperlist {get;set;}
    public List<Return__c> return1 {get;set;}
    public Return__c newReturn {get;set;}
    public Order_Form__c orderformclone = new Order_Form__c();
    public Boolean Page1 {get;set;}
    public Boolean ShowTable {get;set;}
    public Boolean ShowOrderForm {get;set;}


    public ReturnManagementCX(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        con = controller;
        Page1 = true;
        ShowTable = false;
        ShowOrderForm = false;
        ordwrapperlist = new List<resultWrapper>();
        ordformqry = new Order_Form__c();
        orderformclone = new Order_Form__c();
        return1 = new List<Return__c>();
    }

    public void init() {

        ShowTable = true;

        List<Order__c> orders = new List<Order__c>();
        List<resultWrapper> tempwrapper = new List<resultWrapper>();

        if(returnRecord.Order_Form__c != null) {

            ordformqry = [SELECT Id, Name, Account__c, Purchased_Date__c, Status__c FROM Order_Form__c WHERE Id =: returnRecord.Order_Form__c];
            orderformclone = ordformqry.Clone(true,true,true,true);
        }

        if(returnRecord.Order_Form__c == null) {
            ordwrapperlist.clear();
        }

        if(returnRecord.Order_Form__c != null) {

            orders = [SELECT Id, Name, Product__c FROM Order__c WHERE Id =: returnRecord.Order_Form__c];


        }

        for(Order__c ordloop : orders) {
            tempwrapper.add(new resultWrapper(ordloop));
        }

        if(tempwrapper != null) {
            ordwrapperlist = tempwrapper;    
        }
    }

    public void proceed() {
        List<Return__c> returnlist = new List<Return__c>();
        Return__c newReturn = new Return__c();

        Set<Id> newIds = new Set<Id>();

        System.debug('ordformqry v orderformclone>>' + ordformqry +'>>'+orderformclone);

        if(orderformclone.Account__c != ordformqry.Account__c || orderformclone.Purchased_Date__c != ordformqry.Purchased_Date__c || orderformclone.Status__c != ordformqry.Status__c) {
            System.debug('before update ordformqry>>'+ordformqry);
            update ordformqry;
            System.debug('after update ordformqry>>'+ordformqry);
        }



        if(returnlist.size() > 0) {
            insert newReturn;

            Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

            for(Return__c idloop : returnlist) {
                ids.add(idloop.id);
            }

            List<Return__c> retqry = [SELECT Id, Name, Order_Form__c, Order__c FROM Return__c WHERE Id IN : ids];
            System.debug('retqry>>'+ retqry);

            return1 = retqry;  
        }


    }

    public class resultWrapper {
        public Order__c orderlist {get;set;}

        public resultWrapper(Order__c ord) {
            orderlist = ord;
        }
    }

}
```

And here's my vf page:

**ReturnManagementPage**

```
<apex:page standardController="Return__c" extensions="ReturnManagementCX">

    <apex:form id="theForm" rendered="{!Page1}">

        <apex:pageBlock id="block1">

            <apex:pageBlockSection >

                <apex:inputField >
                    <apex:actionSupport action="{!init}" event="onchange"/>
                </apex:inputField>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="orderforminfo" rendered="{!ShowOrderForm}">

                <apex:inputField value="{!ordformqry.Account__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ordformqry.Purchased_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ordformqry.Status__c}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="block2" rendered="{!ShowTable}">

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="block2" title="Order Items">

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ordwrapperlist}" var="ol">

                    <apex:column headerValue="Product" value="{!ol.orderlist.Product__c}"/>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>   

</apex:page>
```

I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your `<apex:inputfield>` is missing value attribute, set the value for
>   the inputfield like `<apex:inputfield value = "{!instanceOfSObject.Field}">`.

*Value of for inputfield is* 
A merge field that references the Salesforce field that is associated with this inputField. For example, if you want to display an input field for an account's name field, use value="{!account.name}". You can't associate this inputField with a formula merge field of type currency if your organization is using dated exchange rates.

Comment: But ordformqry  references the Order_Form__c object in my controller, and I intend to get and display the values of the fields from that object. Any way, I tried modifying it to  e.g.: {!Order_Form__c.Purchased_Date__}, and it displayed this error: Unknown property 'Return__cStandardController.Order_Form__c'

Comment: I think you misunderstood expression "{!SObject.Field}", check the updated one in answer.

Comment: It should be like value = "{!ordformqry.Purchased_Date__c}" if you want to use Purchased_Date__c field on Order_Form__c

Comment: That's what  I actually did, please see the original vf page I've posted.

Comment: <apex:pageBlockSection id="orderforminfo" rendered="{!ShowOrderForm}">

                <apex:inputField value="{!ordformqry.Account__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ordformqry.Purchased_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!ordformqry.Status__c}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
Here's portion of the code from the original vf page I've posted.

Comment: If I am not wrong we are talking about : 
<apex:inputField >
 <apex:actionSupport action="{!init}" event="onchange"/>
</apex:inputField>

are we?

Comment: Oh now I get it, my thought's on the wrong portion of the code. Please forgive me :) Any way, thanks for your help.